# Column properties in data.frame after being converted to char. matrix (transposed).

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know if I can read a data.frame ("a" below) without having "factors" assigned as the properties. I would like the character/string as factor and numbers as numeric (without having to call every columns).

```
x <- matrix(letters[1:9],3)
x<-rbind(x,c(0,2,2))
rownames(x) <- c('c1','c2','c3','c4')
y <- data.frame(x)
z <- t(y)
a <- data.frame(z)      
str(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the condition `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` everytime you create a data.frame:

```
y <- data.frame(x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

a <- data.frame(z,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

change the 4 column of a back to numeric:

```
> a[,4]=as.numeric(a[,4])

> a
   c1 c2 c3 c4
X1  a  b  c  0
X2  d  e  f  2
X3  g  h  i  2

> str(a)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ c1: chr  "a" "d" "g"
 $ c2: chr  "b" "e" "h"
 $ c3: chr  "c" "f" "i"
 $ c4: num  0 2 2
```

Comment: Is there a equivalent argument to "stringsAsfactors" for numbers? I have many datasets of different lenghts, thanks.